# How to make an OS X FUSE file system case insensitive and case preserving

Tags: macos, fuse

The native file system for OS X is case insensitive and case preserving and I would like my OS X Fuse file system to be the same way.

So far if I make my file system case insensitive so that if I have file 'foo' and I do:

> ls 'Foo'

It will show the file info but:

> mv 'foo' 'Foo'

will not work.

If my file system is case sensitive then:

> mv 'foo' 'Foo'

works but not

> ls 'Foo'

I have tried it with

> conn->want |= FUSE_CAP_CASE_INSENSITIVE;

set and not set but it doesn't make any difference. From what I understand this setting doesn't effect the driver anyway.

I noticed that the loopback file system has the same problem.

Is this even possible or is it just a limitation of OSX FUSE?

Comment: Perhaps mounting the fuse fs with the `debug` argument and then following messages in stdout will help you debug the issue.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Any luck figuring it out?

Comment: No, I just decided to make it case insensitive. I think this is a limitation of OSX FUSE.